# can we build web application without masterpage in it

Tags: asp.net

I want to build web application for a college in Microsoft Asp.net 3.5 framework which i have actions to database and login controls for each of the college members,but i feel working  without master page in it for the web application. Is it possible ?Can you Please Specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Right click on your project, select **Add > Add New Item > Web Form**

**Web Form** does not use a master page while the "**Web Form with Master Page**" option does.

Comment: so is it possible for a whole web application to be built without the master page.? @ErwanLent

Comment: @A.r.Naresh Yes, you are not required to create a master page at all.

Comment: yeah can you provide just a small link or something which could provide the information

Comment: @A.r.Naresh My comment says it all. Just create a web form without a master page and start adding in HTML. Have you even tried the above example?